# These two norms of $C^k[a,b]$ are equivalent.

Tags: functional-analysis

In $C^k[a,b]$ we can define
$$
\|f\|_* := \|f\|_\infty + \left\|f^{(k)}\right\|_\infty
$$

and
$$
\|f\|_{**} := \sum_{j=0}^k \left\|f^{(j)}\right\|_\infty$$

It is obvious that $\|f\|_*\leq \|f\|_{**}$. However, how can I show that $K\|f\|_*\geq \|f\|_{**}$ for $K>0$? Any hint?

Comment: is your sum supposed to start at $j=1$? 
Because for $f\equiv 1$ we have $\|f\|_*=1$ and $\|f\|_{**}=0$.
Then $\|\cdot\|_*$ and $\|\cdot\|_{**}$ cannot be equivalent

Comment: What did you try? Did you try to do it for $k=2$, using some Taylor formula?

Comment: The sum starts at $j=0$, someone suggested an edition and I accepted but I did not realised this change.

Comment: I tried it but I did not get anything. What I tried more is: $|g(x)| \leq |g(c)| + (b-a)||g||_\infty$ using the integral formula. However, the $|g(c)| term disturbs me... and I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: For $0\le j\le k,\ f^{j-1}(x)=\int^x_af^j(t)dt$

Comment: $f(a)$ is not $0$ necessarily.

Comment: $\|f^{j-1}\|\le (b-a)\|f^j\|$

Comment: @RubénFernándezFuertes Take Matematleta's first comment, apply the absolute value and the standard estimate on integrals.

Comment: Burt, I mean, why is it true if $f(a)\not= 0$?

Comment: For $k=2$, the result is implied by this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318552/using-second-derivative-to-find-a-bound-for-the-first-derivative (after undoing the assumption $f(0)=f(1)=0$, you get $\|f'\|_\infty \le |f(1)| + \frac12 \|f''\|_\infty$). I don't know how to generalise it (yet)

Comment: Exactly, the thing is that I do not know how to kill this $|f(1)|$ term or whatever...

Comment: @CalvinKhor okay, sorry. So maybe we could proceed by induction?

Comment: Maybe, for now I've typed up the $k=2$ case just so that I know its correct (and if I get the solution for arbitrary $k$ of course I'll update the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's consider $[a,b]=[0,1]$. From [Using second derivative to find a bound for the first derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318552/using-second-derivative-to-find-a-bound-for-the-first-derivative?noredirect=1&lq=1), we know that

> If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $f(0)=f(1)=0$ and $\|f''\|_\infty \le 1$, then $\|f'\|_\infty \le \frac12. \tag{A1}\label{firstineq}$

We now remove the assumptions on $f$. If $\|f''\|_\infty=0$, then it is easy to see that $\|f'-f(1)+f(0)\|_\infty =  \frac12 \|f''\|_\infty$. Otherwise, $\|f''\|_\infty>0$, and by using $\tilde f = \frac{f - f(0)-(f(1)-f(0))x}{\|f''\|_\infty}$, we have
$$ \|f'-f(1)+f(0)\|_\infty \le \frac12 \|f''\|_\infty,$$
so that
$ \|f'\|_\infty \le 2\|f\|_\infty + \frac12\|f''\|_\infty$, and so 
$$ \|f\|_{**} = \|f\|_* + \|f'\|_\infty \le 3 \|f\|_*.$$

Lets record the more general version of \ref{firstineq} above.

> If $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$, then 
>   $ \|f'\|_\infty \le 2\|f\|_\infty + \frac12 \|f''\|_\infty \label{2nd}\tag{A2}$

The constants $2,1/2$ are not necessarily the most useful. Indeed, trying an induction for 3 derivatives leaves us at $\|f''\|\le2\|f'\|+\frac12\|f'''\|\le 4\|f'\| + {\color{red}{2 \times \frac12}}\|f''\| + \frac12 \|f'''\|$; if only $2\times\frac12<1$, this would be a proof for $k=3$. Luckily, the constant can change if we change the domain of $f$. Intuitively, if the domain is bigger, then knowing that $f''$ is small doesn't give such a tight bound on $f'$. So lets consider a function on $[a,b]$. As the supremum norm is translation invariant, we can still take $a=0$. With $f:[0,b]\to\mathbb R$, define
$$ \tilde f:[0,1] \to \mathbb R, \tilde f(x) = f(bx).$$
Applying \ref{2nd} gives
$$ \|\tilde f'\|_\infty \le 2\|\tilde f\|_\infty + \frac12 \|\tilde f''\|_\infty $$
By chain rule, $\|\tilde f^{(n)}\|_\infty = b^n\|f^{(n)}\|_{\infty;b}$, where $\|f\|_{\infty;b} :=\sup_{x\in[0,b]} |f(x)|$, giving

> If $f:[0,b]\to\mathbb R$, then
>   $$ \| f'\|_{\infty;b} \le \frac2b \| f\|_{\infty;b} + \frac{b}{2} \| f''\|_{\infty;b} \label{3rd}\tag{A3}$$

Finally, note that for $f:[0,b]\to\mathbb R$, we can use the bound for functions on $[0,\delta b]\to\mathbb R$, $0<\delta\le 1$ to change the value of the constant further, since $$\sup_{x\in[0,b]} = \sup_{t\in[0,b]}\sup_{x\in[t,t+\delta b]\cap [0,b]}$$ 
which gives
$$ \|f'\|_{\infty;b} = \sup_{t\in[0,b]}\| f'(\cdot+t)\|_{\infty,\delta b} \le \frac2{\delta b} \| f\|_{\infty;b} + \frac{\delta b}{2} \| f''\|_{\infty;b}. $$
This is the version that allows induction to work:

> If $f:[0,b]\to\mathbb R$, then for any $\delta \in (0,1]$,
>   $$  \|f'\|_{\infty;b} \le \frac2{\delta b} \| f\|_{\infty;b} + \frac{\delta b}{2} \| f''\|_{\infty;b}. \tag{A4}\label{final}$$

Let me illustrate the $k=3$ case: first, you remove $\|f'\|_{\infty;b}$ by
$$ \|f'\|_{\infty;b}  \le \frac2b\|f\|_{\infty;b}+\frac{b}2\|f''\|_{\infty;b} \\ $$
Then for $\|f''\|_{\infty;b}$,
$$\|f''\|_{\infty;b} \le \frac2b \|f'\|_{\infty;b} + \frac{b}2 \|f'''\|_{\infty;b} \le \frac4{\delta b^2} \|f\|_{\infty;b}  + \delta \|f''\|_{\infty;b} + \frac{b}2 \|f'''\|_{\infty;b}  $$
By using $\delta=\frac12$, we obtain a bound  $$\|f'\|_{\infty;b} + \|f''\|_{\infty;b} \le C \|f\|_*,$$
where $C=C(b)$.
In general, the induction statement to use is

> $\mathfrak P(n)$: For any $0\le k< n$, there exists $C=C(k,n,b)$ such that for any $\beta\in(0,b]$, and any  $f:[0,b]\to\mathbb R$,
>   $$ \|f^{(k)}\|_{\infty;b} \le C\beta^{-k} \|f\|_{\infty;b} + C \beta^{n-k} \|f^{(n)}\|_{\infty;b}.$$

I took this induction proof and the above main idea from Giovanni Leoni's great book "A First Course In Sobolev Spaces"(2nd edition pg. 202, section on interpolation inequalities.) There, it is proven in greater generality and I highly encourage reading it there.

The base cases $n=2,3$ are above (and $k=0,n$ is not hard). Suppose $\mathfrak P(n)$ is true, and we hope to prove $\mathfrak P(n+1)$. Then for $2\le k\le n$, the induction hypothesis gives  for $\delta\in(0,1]$,
$$ \|f' \|_{\infty;b} \le C(\delta \beta)^{-1} \|f\|_{\infty;b} + C (\delta \beta)^{k-1} \|f^{(k)}\|_{\infty;b},$$
and applying the induction hypothesis to $f'$,
$$ \|f^{(k)} \|_{\infty;b} \le C\beta^{-(k-1)} \|f'\|_{\infty;b} + C \beta^{n-(k-1)} \|f^{(n+1)}\|_{\infty;b}.$$
Combining gives
$$ \|f^{(k)} \|_{\infty;b} \le C\delta^{-1} \beta^{-k} \|f\|_{\infty;b}  + C\delta ^{k-1} \|f^{(k)}\|_{\infty;b} + C \beta^{n+1-k} \|f^{(n+1)}\|_{\infty;b}.$$ 
This gives the result once we take $\delta$ small enough that $C\delta ^{k-1} < 1$.

We are left with $k=1$. In this case, estimate $f'$ by
$$ \|f' \|_{\infty;b} \le C(\delta \beta)^{-1} \|f\|_{\infty;b} + C (\delta \beta)^{n-2} \|f^{(n-1)}\|_{\infty;b},$$
and then estimate $f^{(n-1)}$ by
$$ \|f^{(n-1)} \|_{\infty;b} \le C\beta^{-(n-2)} \|f'\|_{\infty;b} + C \beta^{n-(n-2)} \|f^{(n+1)}\|_{\infty;b}.$$
This gives
$$ \|f' \|_{\infty;b} \le C(\delta\beta)^{-1} \|f\|_{\infty;b}  + C\delta^{n-2}  \|f^{'}\|_{\infty;b} + C \delta^{n-2}\beta^{n} \|f^{(n+1)}\|_{\infty;b}.$$ 
By choosing $C\delta^{n-2}<1$, the proof is finished.

Comment: Simply perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @RubénFernándezFuertes but this isn't an answer for $k>2$, you shouldn't accept it

Comment: well, but I think it is enough to continue. However, I let it unanswered for if someone has a complete answer... Thank you, anyway! Tomorrow I will try my answer.

Comment: @RubénFernándezFuertes I have good news, this result (Gagliardo-Nirenberg interpolation) has a proof in Giovanni Leoni's book, "A First Course In Sobolev Spaces" (2nd edition, though I think the first edition also works). If you try the induction, it will fail if you only have the factor of $1/2$. You actually need to reduce the factor $1/2$ to get $k≥3$(!). Unfortunately it is a series of lemmas before this result is proven, and it is proven in more generality (for any $p\in [1,\infty]$) so it is hard for me to distill an answer out. When I have time, I will try to update this answer.

Comment: Many thanks for everything. I will work it out the next days!

Comment: @RubénFernándezFuertes I believe I have successfully pulled out the $p=q=r=\infty$ case from the proof in Leoni's book. If you see any errors, please let me know.

Comment: ...(I don't know why $n\ge 3$ is needed for the case $k=1$, it looks to me like $n\ge 2$ is enough)

Comment: Sorry for answering so late. I found another solution and I am posting it now, tell me if you agree or something, if you like! Many thanks, anyway. Your solution is great.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found and answer:

Firstly, it is obvious that $||f||_* \leq ||f||_{**}$.

In the other hand, it is sufficient to prove it for $C^k[0,1]$. We can write
\begin{equation}
f(x) = f(c) + \underbrace{f^{(1}(x)(x - c) + \cdots + \frac{f^{(k-1}(c)}{(k-1)!}(x-c)^{k-1}}_{P_{k,c}(x)} + \int_{(c,x)} f^k(t)\frac{(x-t)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\text{d} t
\end{equation}

for every $c,x\in[0,1]$ (note that, because of that, this bound holds for $(x-c)\in [-1,2]$). Taking norms,
$$
|P_{k,c}(x)| \leq 2 ||f||_\infty + ||f^{(n}||_\infty \leq 2||f||_*
$$

Note: If you take $[a,b]$ instead of $[0,1]$ you will have $|P_{n,c}(x)| \leq 2 ||f||_\infty + k(a,b,n)||f^{(n}||_\infty$ with $k(a,b,n)$ a constant.

Lemma: Let $P(t)\in \mathcal{P}^k(I) = \{p(t) = \sum_{j=0}^l c_j t^j: l\leq k, a_j\in \mathbb{R}, t \in I\}$ for I a closed interval. If $|P(t)| < C$ for every $t\in I$, then its coefficients are also bounded.

Proof: the norms 
$$
||p||_1 = \max_{0\leq j\leq k}\{c_j\}, \quad ||p||_2 = \sup_{t\in I}|p(t)|
$$
are equivalent because $\mathcal{P}^k(I)$ is a normed and finite dimensional space.$\square$

In our case, $P_{k,c}\in \mathcal{P}^k([-c,1-c])$. Thus if we bound it, the constant will depend on $c$. To avoid this situation, we can suppose either $c>1/2$ or $c<1/2$. Without lost of generality, suppose $c>1/2$. Then, $(x-c)\in J = [-1,1/2]$.

Hence, since $||P_{k,c}||_2 \leq 2||f||_*$, then, there exists an $\alpha > 0$ such that $||P_{k,c}||_1 \leq 2\alpha||f||_*$, and so $||f^{(j}||_\infty \leq  2\alpha||f||_*$ for all $1\leq j\leq k$. There are not any problems related to the difference

Finally, $||f||_{**}\leq (2\alpha(k-1)+1)||f||_{*}$.

Comment: @CalvinKhor if you write $P_{n,a} = f(x) - f(c) - \text{integral}$ and you take norms you have it because $|f(x)|, |f(c)| \leq ||f||_\infty$ and also $|f^{(n}| \leq ||f^{(n}||_\infty$.

Comment: sorry, I didn't know you were still editing your answer. I'll wait

Comment: @CalvinKhor It remains a little, I'll tell you when I finished, sorry.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I finished.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I edited the Taylor formula. I change the integral limits to $(0,x)$ instead of $(0,1)$. However, I think it is not necessary, because you can iterate the formula $g(x) = g(c) + \int_0^x g'(t)\text{d}t$ for the derivatives.

Comment: some small typos, should be $P_{k,a}(x) = f^{(1)}(\color{red}{c})(x-c)+\dots$, and the integral limits should be from $c$ to $x$ (which may be for $x<c$), when you take norms, you should write $\|P_{k,c}\|_\infty$, the bound should be (i think) $\frac{(b-a)^n}{n!} \|f^{(n)}\|_\infty$. Also you need $P^k(J)$ to be centered at $c$, or include the constant term

Comment: @CalvinKhor Yes, there were a lot of mistakes. I have corrected all of them, I think.

Note that, $n>1$, so I think the bound should be $\int_c^x |x-t|^k d t \leq b^k \int_c^x  dt \leq b^k(b-a)$, isn't it?

Comment: for $x>c$ you can integrate directly $(x-t)^k\ge 0$, and your inequality gives $\le 0$ if e.g. $[a,b]=[-1,0]$. Also  $\|p\|_1$ should be $\max \color{red}{|a_j |}$. I think these errors (previous comment as well) have not yet been fixed

Comment: @CalvinKhor Maybe it would be better with the iteration I mentioned before.

Comment: Basically I think the strategy is to prove $|f^{(k)}(c)| \le \alpha \|f\|_*$, is this correct? I'm not 100% sure how to show that $\alpha$ does not depend on $c$ so that we can take a sup in $c$.

Comment: I'll write a new version of the lemma because it is true that it is a little bit messy.

Comment: Well, I'm convinced that it works after explcitly trying it for $k=2,3$, maybe the proof could be clearer. Good job